# How to debug custom loss function in Keras?

Tags: debugging, printing, callback, keras, tensor

I created the custom loss function with parameter.

```python
def w_categorical_crossentropy(weights):
  def loss(y_true, y_pred):
  print(weights)
  print("----")
  print(weights.shape)
  final_mask = K.zeros_like(y_pred[:, 0])
  y_pred_max = K.max(y_pred, axis=1)
  y_pred_max = K.reshape(y_pred_max, (K.shape(y_pred)[0], 1))
  y_pred_max_mat = K.cast(K.equal(y_pred, y_pred_max), K.floatx())
  return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true)
return loss
```

Now, i need to control weights parameter value, but print function doesn't work properly. Is there any way for printing weights value?

Comment: The best way to debug is to create some simple fake data which you know what the result is (or can be easily calculated by hand), and compare the result from the function with the true value.

Answer (score 3):

What I sometimes do (Not the best solution for sure, nor does always possible) is just replace the K backend by np and test it with some simple data. Here is an example

original Keras function:

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    means = K.reshape(y_pred[:, 0], (-1, 1))
    stds = K.reshape(y_pred[:, 1], (-1, 1))
    var = K.square(stds)
    denom = K.sqrt(2 * np.pi * var)
    prob_num = - K.square(y_true - means) / (2 * var)
    prob = prob_num - denom
    r = K.exp(prob - old_prediction)
    return -K.mean(K.minimum(r * advantage, K.clip(r, min_value=1 - self.LOSS_CLIPPING, max_value=1 + self.LOSS_CLIPPING) * advantage))
```

testing function:

```
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    means = np.reshape(y_pred[:, 0], (-1, 1))
    stds = np.reshape(y_pred[:, 1], (-1, 1))
    var = np.square(stds)
    print(var.shape)
    denom = np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * var)
    print(denom.shape)
    prob_num = - np.square(y_true - means) / (2 * var)
    prob = prob_num - denom
    r = np.exp(prob - old_prediction)
    print(r.shape)
    cliped = np.minimum(r * advantage, np.clip(r, a_min=1 - LOSS_CLIPPING, a_max=1 + LOSS_CLIPPING) * advantage)
    print(cliped.shape)
    return -np.mean(cliped)
```

Testing it:

```
LOSS_CLIPPING = 0.2
y_pred = np.array([[2,1], [1, 1], [5, 1]])
y_true = np.array([[1], [3], [2]])
old_prediction = np.array([[-2], [-5], [-6]])
advantage = np.array([[ 0.51467506],[-0.64960159],[-0.53304715]])
loss(y_true, y_pred)
```

After running above, results:

```
(3, 1)
(3, 1)
(3, 1)
(3, 1)
0.43409555193679816
```